Prove that $ T(f(x)) = \int_0^xf(t)dt $ is injective, but it is not a surjective and a linear transformation.
In friedberg linear algebra  p.97, problem 15
problem is "Prove that the following function $T$ is injective, and it is not a surjective and a linear transformation."
$$ T(f(x)) = \int_0^xf(t)dt $$ $$T: P(\Bbb{R})\to P(\Bbb{R})  $$
How should I get started in the first step?

What is the definition of a linear transformation? Use it to test $T$.

thank you for feedback and answer

Not surjective: $(Tf)(0)=0$.

thank you i'll try it like that

The definite integral of an integrable function is a linear map $\int_0^x (a f + b g)(\xi) d\xi$, because sum and coefficents can be exchanged with the integrate operation. The map is injective, because an integral is zero for all upper x-values only, if the integrand is zero (almost everywhere). Its not surjective because  primitives of integrable functions, even discontinuous ones, are (absolutely) continuous.

Given two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with the condition $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$, can you conclude that $f(x)=g(x)$(that implies injectivity) Hint:Differentiate it on both sides.

What is $P(R)$? That seems to be extremely relevant! In fact, a complete answer should begin with proving that for all $f\in P(R)$, we have $T(f)\in P(R)$

"With my lack of ability, I can't start this problem." <<< I strongly advise you to stop writing and saying things like this. Words have power and if you insist that you cannot do something then it becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy. A convenient, comfortable, lazy, self-fulfilling prophecy.

All right. I will speak carefully. thank you

@Stef I agree with you, absolutely true.

$ T(f(x)) = \int_0^xf(t)dt$, linearity is very easy. If $T(f(x)) = T(g(x)) \iff \int_0^xf(t)dt = \int_0^xg(t)dt \iff \int_0^x(f(t) - g(t))dt = 0$, for all $x$, so differenciate both side with respect to $x$, we have $f(x) - g(x) = 0$, as $f,g$ are polynomial so it is differentiable. Hence $f=g$, so $T$ is injective. $T$ is not surjective because $T(f)(0) = 0$ for all $f \in P(\Bbb{R})$. Now $x + 1 \in P(\Bbb{R})$, so if there exists an $f \in P(\Bbb{R})$ such that $T(f(x)) = x+1$, but then $T(f)(0) = 0 = 1$, which is a contradiction.

I would write $T(f)(0)$ or $T(f(x))(0)$. The notation $T(f(0))$ can be extremely confusing for a student, because it's wrong: we're not taking the image of $f(0)$.

I don't understand this point. I calculate $T(f(x)) \in P(\Bbb{R})$ at the point of $x =0$

thanks very helpful

You are welcome :-) You can upvote and accept the answer if you feel it is helpful. As you are new to this site, it is a good practice.

@Afntu Say $f(x) = 3x^2+2$. Then $T(f(x))=x^3+2x$ and $T(f(x))(0)=0^3+2\times 0=0$ but $f(0)=2$, so $T(f(0))=T(2)=2x$. So when you write $T(f(x))$ you rely on everyone knowing that you really mean $T(f(x))(0)$ and not $T\left(\quad f(0)\quad \right)$

Ok, I got your point. My notation is confusing. I will change that. Thanks for pointing out @Stef
